# Подсчет символов в строке с помощью ASCII значений символов

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть строка с латинскими буквами, символами и цифрами.  Как подсчитать количество строчных, заглавных букв и цифр отдельно, не используя регулярные выражения. А с помощью ASCII значений символов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Диапазоны известны. Поэтому просто перебирайте символы в строке и считайте сколько из них и в какой диапазон попадает.

Для цифр это диапазон от 48 до 57 (включительно).

Для заглавных от 65 до 90 (включительно).

Для строчных от 97 до 122 (включительно).

Comment: Сами символы же вполне можно использовать. Зачем считать числа?

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно. Но вопрос стоит  `с помощью ASCII значений символов`. Как я понимаю, так поставлена учебная задача.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вам подойдет такое решение:
В классе оболочке [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) есть набор подходящих для решения Вашей задачи методов.

[static boolean isDigit(char ch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-) - проверяет является ли символ числом

[static boolean isLetter(char ch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-) -(что очевидно) буква ли

[static boolean isWhitespace(char ch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) Пробел ли

и так далее...Добавлю что там-же есть возможность реализовать проверку на заглавная/прописная,буква/число и куча других возможностей.Все (большая часть) методов статичные.
Касательно ASCII формата т.к в Unicode первые 128 символов идентичны ASCII можно использовать в качестве временного хранилища тип byte...